# How prove that $(a_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is convergent with $a_{0}=1$, $a_{n+1}= \sqrt{2a_{n}}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, recursion

> Prove that $(a_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is convergent with $a_{0}=1$,
>   $a_{n+1}= \sqrt{2a_{n}}$ and calculate its limit.
>
> You got the info that the square-root-function is strictly monotonic
>   increasing and also continuous.

I'm very confused how this could be solved because there isn't really a sequence given here. It seems to be a recursive one and I also don't know how to form $a_{n+1}$.

Could I form it to $a_{n}+ a_{1}$ ?(I don't care if it's useful here but I'd like to know if this would be correct at first.)

---

I have started by forming to $a_{n}$:

$$2a_{n} = (a_{n+1})^{2}$$

$$a_{n}=\frac{(a_{n+1})^{2}}{2}$$

Then I also formed to $a_{1}:$

$$a_{n}+ a_{1} = \sqrt{2a_{n}}$$

$$a_{1} = \sqrt{2a_{n}} - a_{n}$$

But it seems like this won't lead to anything.. Also I don't know what we can do with the given info, $a_{0} = 1$, the continuity and monotonic increasing...

Comment: Consider the sequence $\log(a_n)$

Answer (score 4):

The most basic, but still readable proof (in my opinion) is by using the following theorem:

> A monotonically increasing, bounded sequence of real numbers is convergent.

So we need to prove that $a_n$ is increasing and bounded. Specifically, I will prove that $1\leq a_n \leq a_{n+1} \leq 2$ for all $n$ using induction.

Base case: The inequality clearly holds for $n = 0$, since $1 \leq 1 \leq \sqrt 2 \leq 2$.

Induction step: Assume the inequality holds for $n = k$, i.e. that $1\leq a_k \leq a_{k+1}\leq 2$. We want to show
$$
1 \leq a_{k+1} \leq a_{k+2} \leq 2
$$
The first inequality follows from the induction hypothesis and transitivity of $\leq$ (we assumed $1 \leq a_k$ and $a_k \leq a_{k+1}$). For the second inequality, we have
$$
a_{k+1} = \sqrt{a_{k+1}\cdot a_{k+1}} \leq \sqrt{2a_{k+1}} = a_{k+2}
$$
where we used $ a_{k+1}\leq 2$, as well as the monotonically increasing nature of the square root.

For the last inequality, we have
$$
a_{k+2} = \sqrt{2\cdot a_{k+1}} \leq  \sqrt{2\cdot 2} = 2
$$
which concludes the proof that $1 \leq a_{k+1} \leq a_{k+2} \leq 2$.

Answer (score 1):

By induction $$a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2a_n}=\sqrt{2\cdot\sqrt{2a_{n-1}} }=2^{1/2}2^{1/4}a_{n-1}^{1/4}=...=a_0\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}2^{\frac{1}{2^{i}}}.$$

As robjohn suggest, define $b_{n+1}=\log(a_{n+1})$ and conclude.

Comment: @cnmesr: What do you mean ?

Comment: I'm just shocked that was a task from an old exam, the first task (the so called warm-up-one). I would never get to that solution and it's just frustrating. Also I would have never expected to use induction proof to calculate / find the limit of it... But thank you very much for your answer, I got much to do I guess.

Comment: There is no other, easier way to solve this task by the way?

Comment: @cnmesr: I don't think that it's a complicate way... But if you want you can show that it's increasing and upper bounded by 2...

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}=\left(\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}}\right)^{1/2}\tag{1}
$$
Therefore, by induction
$$
\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}=\left(\frac{a_1}{a_0}\right)^{1/2^{n-1}}\tag{2}
$$
Since
$$
\begin{align}
a_n
&=a_0\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{a_k}{a_{k-1}}\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^n2^{1/2^k}\\
&=2^{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n1/2^k}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Since $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n1/2^k$ converges, the sequence converges. Since $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty1/2^k=1$, this also tells to what the sequence converges.

Answer (score 1):

With $a_0=1$, $a_{n+1}= \sqrt{2a_{n}}$, so show $(a_n)$ is monotone and bounded.

---

First show $(a_n)$ is bounded.

Let $P(n)$ be the statement $1\leq a_n\leq 2$.

**Base Case**

We have $a_0=1$, and $1\leq 1\leq 2$.

**Inductive Step**

Let $P(k)$ be true: $1\leq a_{k}\leq 2$. Now check validity of $P(k+1)$ from assumed truth of $P(k)$. Since

$$\sqrt{2\cdot1}\leq a_{k+1}= \sqrt{2a_{k}}\leq \sqrt{2\cdot 2}=2$$
we have $1\leq a_{k+1}\leq 2$ as required, and so $(a_n)$ is bounded.

---

Now show $(a_n)$ is monotone.

**Base Case**

We have $a_1=\sqrt{2a_0}=\sqrt{2}\geq a_0=1$. Now $a_2=\sqrt{2a_1}=\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}}$ and so $a_2>a_1$.

**Inductive Step**

Let $P(k)$ be true: $a_{k}\geq a_{k-1}$. Now check validity of $P(k+1)$ from assumed truth of $P(k)$. Since
$$a_k=\sqrt{2a_{k-1}},\quad\text{and}\quad a_{k+1}=\sqrt{2a_k}$$
then, since the square-root-function is strictly monotonic increasing
$$a_{k+1}=\sqrt{2a_k}\geq a_k=\sqrt{2a_{k-1}}$$
since we assumed $a_{k}\geq a_{k-1}$.

---

Hence the sequence is monotone increasing, bounded above by $2$, and so must converge to some limit $L$, say. Then
$$\sqrt{2a_{n}}\to \sqrt{2L}, \qquad\text{as $n\to\infty$}$$
But the sequences $(a_{n})$ and $(a_{n+1})$ converge to the same limit, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1})=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{2a_{n}})$$ 
from which:
$$L=\sqrt{2L}$$
and so $L=2$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Always start by evaluating a few terms.

$$a_0=1=2^0,a_1=\sqrt2=2^{1/2},a_2=\sqrt{2\sqrt2}=2^{1/2+1/4},a_3=\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt2}}=2^{1/2+1/4+1/8},\cdots$$

As you can show by induction (or by the geometric series formula),

$$a_n=2^{1-1/2^n}=\frac2{\sqrt{\sqrt{\cdots\sqrt2}}}.$$